# Periodic background jobs on Rails & Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, screen-scraping, web-scraping

I'm developing a Rails app which gives pricing data on various products by scraping prices from 3rd party sites (similar to http://railscasts.com/episodes/190-screen-scraping-with-nokogiri).

Since I'm new to programming, right now I am manually doing this by putting my code in a rake task. The tasks loops through all the products in my database and updates their price through scraping. It takes a few hours to complete (since there are 1000s of products) but most of the time spent is from calling  **sleep** so I can rate limit myself. Right now I'm calling the rake task manually from command line but I'd like to have a weekly periodic job that automatically runs in the background.

After a bit of research, it seems like there are several ways to do this (**Resque, DelayedJob, Cron/Whenever**) but I'm not sure which would best fit my need. In addition, I'm deploying through Heroku so I want to make sure I don't waste money on worker dynos; right now this is just a side project so I wouldn't want to spend that much.

What would be a simple and cost efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 6):

I'm currently using the [Heroku Scheduler](https://addons.heroku.com/scheduler). It can run tasks every day, every hour or every 10 minutes. It's extremely easy to use:

1. Install the add-on with `heroku addons:add scheduler:standard`
2. Go to your app in the Heroku website, select the Scheduler add-on and add a new job. You do this by defining the task (`rake name_of_your_task`), the frequency and the next run. And done.

There are, however, several problems:

1. You need to give a valid credit card to be able to use this add-on even though it is, in principle, free.
2. The Scheduler runs one-off processes that will count toward your dyno-hours.
3. Heroku only gives you 750 free dyno hours per app.

This is what the Scheduler's wiki has to say about [Long-running jobs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/scheduler#longrunning-jobs):

> Scheduled jobs are meant to execute short running tasks or enqueue longer running tasks into a background job queue. Anything that takes longer than a couple of minutes to complete should use a worker dyno to run.

So my advice here would be:

1. Break down your rake task into smaller chunks meant to run only for a couple minutes.
2. Run these tasks more periodically (you don't even have a weekly option using the Scheduler).
3. Keep an eye on your dyno hours. You can do so [here](https://api.heroku.com/invoices/current). 750 hours amount to 31 days and 6 hours. So you have at least 6 hours to work with in those 31-day months. If your app is not being used, you can also use the following command to turn it off so it stops counting the regular dyno hours.

   ```
   heroku ps:scale web=0
   ```

   And you can scale it back up with

   ```
   heroku ps:scale web=1
   ```

Unfortunately, there's no such thing as free computing power.

Comment: Wow, now that I look at this answer, I must really like lists :D

Comment: If I'm unable to break my tasks into smaller chunks, any suggestions on what I should do?

Comment: What have you tried? Are you scraping only pages you defined? If you are, then you can put them inside an array and have a function that depending on the day of the week, starts at a certain index and ends in another index of the array. If you are scraping a ton of pages you did not define, then you can set a hard limit. A 1000 products per day for example. So you should have a counter and when it reaches 1000 you save the url or the id of the next page you want to scrap and continue the following day where you left off.